# C# webbrowser threadstateexception (Однопоточный контейнер)

Tags: c#, многопоточность, webbrowser

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException:
> Создание экземпляра элемента
> управления ActiveX
> '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2'
> невозможно: текущий поток не находится
> в однопоточном контейнере.    в
> System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase..ctor(String
> clsidString)    в
> System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser..ctor()

Выглядит все примерно так:
Есть функция, в которой подается на очередь в пул потоков анонимный метод. В этом методе Вызывается функция, которая, в свою очередь, вызывает еще одну, которая создает экземпляр webbrowser, и со 2 вызова этой функции происходит ошибка, которую я описал выше. Пробовал ставить атрибут `[STAThread]` на функции, где создается экземпляр, но результат тот же.

Comment: @azaznioo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Все потоки из пула потоков по умолчанию являются MTA потоками. Если вам нужно создавать контрол обязательно в другом потоке, то придется делать это руками:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(MyMethod);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал этого.