# Создать таск с параметром STA

Tags: c#, многопоточность, com

Мне нужно запустить форму с ком-объектом в отдельном потоке, чтобы результаты действия объекта на форме(я ее невидимой запускаю) отображались на главной форме в реальном времени. Но если создавать форму с ком-объектом через task, то появляется ошибка *{"Создание экземпляра элемента управления ActiveX '54d38bf7-b1ef-4479-9674-1bd6ea465258' невозможно: текущий поток не находится в однопоточном контейнере."}*, вот я нашел решение для тредов: [C# webbrowser threadstateexception (Однопоточный контейнер)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412073/c-webbrowser-threadstateexception-%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80) . А можно ли как-то тип апартаментов указать при создании тасков? Или таски находятся уровнем выше и понятием таким не оперируют и придется все делать с помощью threads? Спасибо.

UPD: На второй форме создается com-объект, который проверяет доступность подключения по введенным данным.

```
public void IsConnectAvailiable(string host, string login, string password)
{   
    rdc.OnLoginComplete += rdc_OnLoginComplete;
    timer1.Interval = 10000;
    rdc.Server = host;
    rdc.UserName = login;
    rdc.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;  
    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdc.GetOcx();    
    secured.ClearTextPassword = password;
    rdc.Connect();  


}
```

Нельзя просто создать такой объект, не привязывая его к форме, потому что вылетает исключение:

**{"Выдано исключение типа \"System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException\"."}**

А чтобы форма не фризилась, пока проверяется состояние подключения, нужно было вынести эту проверку в отдельный поток, а поток должен быть STA, потому что (я не совсем еще разобрался) это особенность com-технологии. В общем какая-то нетривиальная задача. Тут все смешалось - com, формы, треды, кони.

Comment: Так не получится.Всю работу выполняет объект, который привязан к форме. Сейчас обновлю пост.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого можно достичь, запуская таск с нужным [таск скедулером](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-7.0). Таск скедулер занимается тем, что распределяет таски на конкретные потоки. В [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://web.archive.org/web/20160722213435/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx) существует [StaTaskScheduler](https://web.archive.org/web/20160724072136/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx):

```
var staScheduler = new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // код
    },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    staScheduler);
```

Исходник скедулера можно скопировать [отсюда](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=MSDN-samples).

**UPD**

Одного STA скедулера может быть недостаточно, потому как он не качает очередь сообщений. Подробности в [ответе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371891/1985167), там же ссылка на работающую имплементацию.

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на то что нужно.